# Recompress static page slide show to keep sharpness but greatly reduce file size with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, slideshow

I have an hour long slide show (e.g. powerpoint) video, over 1GB of video data, but I don't have the original slide show.  It is in VP9 format.   (Does VP9 perform poorly for temporal encoding of successive identical frames?)

If I try to compress it further using ffmpeg libx264, it adds bluriness and other ugly artifacts.

Is this simply because of default settings fed into the encoder, vs the encoder not working properly?

Are there ideal settings (and a best codec whether libx264 or other) to re-compress a VP9 of a powerpoint maximally so that it is much smaller file size and still looks crisp and sharp, taking full advantage of successive frames being identical?  Preferably settings that ignore subtle changes, declaring successive frames "same" without encoding frame-to-frame noise.  This would be to both save bandwidth and for aesthetic reasons, so slides look perfectly still.

Comment: Share the readout of `ffmpeg -i input`

Comment: There are several answers here [linux - How to Simply Remove Duplicate Frames from a Video using ffmpeg - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966394/how-to-simply-remove-duplicate-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg) that solve this in different ways.

Comment: Thanks!  The answer in that link using scene to detect changes compressed it by more than 8x with no loss of sharpness.  Exactly what I was looking for.